# How to make set on useffect change immediately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, next.js

I make an ecommerce site
I am trying to display the page with the details of a product:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";

import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const ProductPage = () => {
const router = useRouter();
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/products?id=${router.query.id}`);
      const currentProduct = response.data;
      setLoading(false);
      setProduct(currentProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  fetchProduct();
}, [router.query.id]);


return (
  
<Layout title={product.name}>
{loading ? (
<div className="text-center">Loading...</div>
) : (
<div className="max-w-lg mx-auto p-5">
<h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-5">{product.name}</h1>
<img
         src={product.imageUrl}
         alt={product.name}
         className="w-full mb-5"
       />
<p className="mb-5">{product.description}</p>
<p className="text-xl font-bold mb-5">
Price: {product.price}
</p>
<Link href="/" legacyBehavior>
<a className="btn btn-primary">Go back to the products list</a>
</Link>
</div>
)}
</Layout>
);
};

export default ProductPage;
```

The values ​​are not displayed so I put some console.log
When I put a console.log in the "try" product returns an empty object, and when I put the console.log after the useffect the product returns an object with my values

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "isLoading" state in false whene the "product" state when the state has finished setting. In order to do that you need to add 1 more useEffect to listen for changes in the product state, for that you must add the "product" state as a dependency of the useEffect.

Try the next code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";

import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const ProductPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/products?id=${router.query.id}`);
        const currentProduct = response.data;
        setProduct(currentProduct);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchProduct();
  }, [router.query.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [product]);

  return (
    <Layout title={product.name}>
      {loading ? (
        <div className="text-center">Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="max-w-lg mx-auto p-5">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-5">{product.name}</h1>
          <img
            src={product.imageUrl}
            alt={product.name}
            className="w-full mb-5"
          />
          <p className="mb-5">{product.description}</p>
          <p className="text-xl font-bold mb-5">Price: {product.price}</p>
          <Link href="/" legacyBehavior>
            <a className="btn btn-primary">Go back to the products list</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ProductPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` hook does not update the state value instantly. There are a lot of things happening when you change the state, like batching state updates, recomputing DOM manipulations, re-rendering components, etc.

If you want to know what is going to be set as your state, log the argument that you are passing to the `setProduct` function. You may also use React dev tools.